# Q: How can I Convert a list of URL domains into a full url

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a list of thousands of URL domains but have copied some into an example here([spreadsheet here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WoNNSgGS5kpZ8uV1HQ2kWQ-RkcsA91yt9tL0nDZu-NE/edit?usp=sharing)) and was looking for a way to convert them into their full URL, as I need the full URL for something I am doing further down the line.

For example all-about-test.eu would become http://all-about-test.eu/

As the URLS might differ between www., https, http etc I cant simply concat this onto the front.

I had a look for google sheet functions that might be able to do this, but couldn't find any.

Comment: How would you know which protocol to use for your URL / whether to use www? Would the fact that the URL is reachable with a certain protocol be a sufficient criteria? What if different protocols are supported?

Comment: It would be the protocol with no redirects, for example if you put 3f.dk into chrome it changes to https://www.3f.dk/. I need the http part of the URL to be correct. I dont have much experience but in theory if a URL could be both http or https with no redirects (which I don't think it can), then either would do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [UrlFetchApp.fetch](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params) in order to try accessing the different URLs with the different protocols, specifying the parameter `followRedirects: false`. You would then check the HTTP response code (see [getResponseCode()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/http-response#getResponseCode())), and return the URL if it's an acceptable response code:

```
function returnFullURL(domain) {
  const options = ["https://","http://", "www.", "https://www.", "http://www.", ""]; // Possible protocols, change if necessary
  const badCodes = [404,301,302,303,307,308]; // Acceptable response codes, change if necessary
  for (let i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
    const url = options[i] + domain;
    try {
      const params = { 
        muteHttpExceptions: true,
        followRedirects: false
      }
      const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(options[i] + domain, params);
      const code = response.getResponseCode();
      if (!badCodes.includes(code)) return url;
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }
  return "No combination allowed";
}
```

You could then use this as a [Custom function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions):

[image]

#### Note:

- I'm not sure whether these are the appropriate HTTP response status codes to check, and whether these are all the possibilities for protocols, www subdomains, etc., but this should give you a start.

#### Edit:

As an alternative, you could build all URLs with a single call to your function, instead of calling it for every domain. In order to do that, copy and call the following function and specify the range for all domains (in your sample sheet, that would be `=returnAllURLs(A2:A18)`):

```
function returnAllURLs(domains) {
  const options = ["https://","http://", "www.", "https://www.", "http://www.", ""]; // Possible protocols, change if necessary
  const badCodes = [404,301,302,303,307,308]; // Acceptable response codes, change if necessary
  return domains.map(domain => {
    for (let i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
      const url = options[i] + domain[0];
      try {
        const params = { 
          muteHttpExceptions: true,
          followRedirects: false
        }
        const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(options[i] + domain[0], params);
        const code = response.getResponseCode();
        if (!badCodes.includes(code)) return [url];
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    }
    return ["No combination allowed"];
  });
}
```

#### Related:

- [HTTP response status codes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status)

Comment: Hi, This has been working great. However about a thousand URL's in, the cell with "returnfullurl()" has been stuck on "Loading... I have left it for a couple hours but nothing seemed to change. Any ideas why this happened? I tried flattening the formula for the cells that had finished getting the URL, but that didn't change anything.

Comment: @WasHere I cannot reproduce this. Is this not working for some domains, or it just starts not working when you call this function many times? In any case, I provided an alternative code which you can use to build all the URLs with a single call to your function, instead of calling it in a different cell for each domain. Let me know if that is helpful to you.